# Update default select option when filtering select list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

I have been trying to filter a list of options that are displayed in a drop down list based on a radio button selection.

```
<div>
    <div ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="type" ng-value="1" ng-model="selectedType" />A</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="type" ng-value="2" ng-model="selectedType" />B</label>
        <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in options | filter:{type:selectedType}">
            <option value="">&lt;Select&gt;</option>
        </select>
        <hr/>
        <div>Type: {{selectedType}}</div>
        <div>Option: {{selectedOption}}</div>
    </div>
</div>

function sampleCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.selectedType = 1;

    $scope.selectedOption = 0;

    $scope.options = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'bread',
        type: 1
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'sugar',
        type: 2
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'tea',
        type: 1
    }, {
        id: 4,
        name: 'coffee',
        type: 2
    }, {
        id: 5,
        name: 'butter',
        type: 2
    }];
}
```

here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hB6M/5/)

I have a default '' option that should be displayed each time the user changes the type.
Now it does filter my options based on the type. however, it does not change my model when the filter changes to .

please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I am unable to understand your issue - do you mean to point out the behaviour where, when changing from option B to A, the select model is not reset and still holds the previous selection?

Comment: Yes. That is what i meant. Sorry if my question was not clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heBgd/)

Basically, when the user changes the type by switching between the radio buttons, the `watch` will be triggered that will reset the selected option.

Thus, when changing the types, it ensures that the model associated with the selected option is reset.

```
$scope.$watch('selectedType', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        $scope.selectedOption = null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying @callmekatootie's answer:

You don't need the parameters `newValue` and `oldValue` in this instance:

```
$scope.$watch('selectedType', function() {
    $scope.selectedOption = 0;
});
```

I also changed from `$scope.selectedOption = null` back to the init value since `$watch` is triggered during onload. This could prevent other issues later on.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jon23781/uNQN4/)

Comment: if i dont check newValue and oldValue, it will always change it. not something that I want. thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @vaibinewbee You mean that if you are on type A and click on type A that it will change it to default? If that is what you are referring to then that is not true, because a radio buttons value only changes when another radio button is selected. I am not sure I understand. My JsFiddle works identical to callmekatootie's with the values and code supplied. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: well this is a very stand alone example. looking at a bigger picture, for instance when you are modifying data from an existing data model, and setting your selected value in the dropdown list based on an existing property on an object. in this case it will always set it to null when the view loads for the first time. this is something i am trying to do. so it does not work for me. As I said, I like your suggestion.

Comment: Understood and yes you are correct, in most instances you would need to watch the new and old values so it is good to know and good to use. I was supplying a simplified example for the code you had provided. Just to be clear I wasn't lobbying for an accepted answer, just giving an option that's why I credited callmekatootie and called out "in this instance". Either way, glad you got it resolved and best of luck. :)